# Why use an external database with Matlab?

Tags: database, matlab, rdbms

**Why should you use an external database (e.g. Mysql) when working with (large/growing) Data?**

I know of some projects which use SQL databases, but I can't see the advantage you get from doing this in contrast to just storing everything in .mat files (as for example stated here: http://www.matlabtips.com/how-to-store-large-datasets/)

Where is this necessary? Where does this approach simplify things?

Answer (score 3):

Regarding growing data, let's take an example where, on a production line, you would measure different sources with different sensors:

```
Experiment.Date = '2014-07-18 @ 07h28';
Experiment.SensorType = 'A';
Experiment.SensorSerial = 'SENSOR-00012-A';
Experiment.SourceType = 'C';
Experiment.SourceSerial = 'SOURCE-00143-C';
Experiment.SensorPositions = 180 * linspace(0, 359, 360) / pi;
Experiment.SensorResponse = rand(1, 360);
```

And store these experiments on disk using .mat files:

```
experiment.2013-01-02.0001.mat
experiment.2013-01-02.0002.mat
experiment.2013-01-02.0003.mat
experiment.2013-01-03.0004.mat
...
experiment.2014-07-18.0001.mat
experiment.2014-07-18.0002.mat
```

So now, if I ask you:

- "what is the typical response of sensors of type `B` when the source is of type `E`" ?

Or:

- "Which sensor has best performances to measure sources of type `C` ? Sensors `A` or sensors `B` ?"
- "How performances of these sensors degrade with time ?"
- "Did modification we made last july to production line improved lifetime of sensors `A` ?"

Loading in memory all these `.mat` files, to check if date, sensor and source type are correct and then calculate min,mean,max responses, and other statistics is gonna be very painful and time consuming + writing custom code for file selection!

Building a data-base on top of these .mat files can be very useful to "SELECT/JOIN/..." elements of interest and then perform further statistic or operations.

NB: The database does not replace .mat files (i.e. the information), it just a practical and standard way to quickly select some of them upon conditions without having to load and parse everything.

Comment: it's worth pointing that there are ways to load only parts of variables from MAT-files: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/import_export/load-parts-of-variables-from-mat-files.html

Comment: @Amro Here, this still means opening all files (maybe thousand of them) just to check if properties are the right ones + writing custom logic for selecting appropriate ones. Limiting ourselves to current context of large/growing data set, a database query seems more appropriate: faster, easy to extend/tune with proven SELECT/JOIN/ORDERBY/WHERE selectors, plus can be manipulated outside matlab context (web interface, etc...).

Comment: @Amro Hummm ... ok ... if many variables in only one file ... sorry was still thinking in the case of many files ;)

Comment: Obviously a model of flat MAT-files is quite different from a proper RDBMS system. But one should always consider the language strengths and weaknesses when writing code; in the case of MATLAB, we can save all those experiments in one MAT-file reducing the IO overhead. We could also create a structure array, which gives us the flexibility of array indexing and slicing, and makes answering the sort of queries you mentioned relatively easy.

Comment: if the data will often be used outside of MATLAB, then it certainly makes sense to store it in a shared database, were it can be easily accessed from many applications. This will come with all the benefits that traditional databases has to offer (transactions, concurrency, data integrity, fault tolerance, etc..)